# How are two entities with a 1:N relationship related?

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

So I have two entities Property and Item. Property and Item have a 1:N relationship respectively. a person can add several items in Property.

Now I want to build a report through SSRS such that some information need to come from Property entity and some from Item entity. Is there any way I can put a join on these two entities? Is there a common ID that CRM 2011 creates when two entities have a 1:N relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Item should have a PropertyId value on it.  Does it not?

Comment: YES!! I just ran a `select *` query on Items and there is a Relationship ID. Thanks Daryl.